# unable to get data table images in pdf when we print the data tables using data table pdf button. it just shows empty data instead of images

Tags: jquery

While downloading the data from DataTable as a PDF... Images that are present in the data table are missing. So, How to get my PDF without losing Images from a data table

```
                        buttons: [{
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                        exportOptions : {
                            stripHtml: false
                        }
                    },'copy', 'excel', 'pdf']

 $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#datatable').DataTable();

                //Buttons examples
                var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable({
                    lengthChange: false,
                    buttons: [{
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                        exportOptions : {
                            stripHtml: false
                        }
                    },'copy', 'excel', 'pdf']
                });

                table.buttons().container()
                        .appendTo('#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
            } );
```

While Downloading the PDf from a data table, images are missing(showing Empty).